# Is there a "sparkup" (vim) for Visual Studio?

Tags: html, visual-studio

[Sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) allows shortcut notation for HTML markup that expands out and is for Vim.

Is there anything like this for Visual Studio [2010]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once seen Zen Coding for VS from DevExpress. I do not know if that works with the free version:

http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2010/11/16/video-zen-coding-free-coderush-plugin.aspx